# How to run html codes in pdf format in R Markdown

Tags: html, r, pdf, r-markdown

**Problem summary:**
I have a data including a couple of HTML codes in one of its columns. I am using this data to obtain an article look (Attached codes below.) When R Markdown renders the file to HTML format, it looks perfect but I want to get same look in pdf format, as well.

Here is my data:

```
data <- structure(list(title = c("Fifth Third Bank has applied for a national bank charter", 
"Fifth Third lets customers access paychecks early"), published = structure(c(1559325007, 1624626780), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), fullcontent = c("<div><img src=\"https://bankinnovation.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Screen-Shot-2019-05-31-at-1.36.34-PM.png\" title=\"Fifth Third Bank has applied for a national bank charter | Bank Innovation | Bank Innovation\"/><br/><div><div>&#13; &#13; &#13; &#13; &#13; <div>&#13; <h3>Fifth Third Bank has applied for a national bank charter</h3>&#13; &#13; &#13; &#13; </div>&#13; &#13; &#13; &#13; &#13; &#13; &#13; <div>&#13; &#13; &#13; &#13; &#13; <p class=\"wp-caption-text thumb-caption\">Wikimedia Commons / EEJCC</p>&#13; &#13; &#13; </div>&#13; &#13; &#13; &#13; <article><div> <div> <p>Cincinnati-based Fifth Third Bank has applied for a national bank charter as it expands its suite of products and services. On Thursday, the bank said it had filed an application with the Office of the Comptroller of the Currency to convert from an Ohio state-chartered bank to a national bank. A national charter will ensure<a href=\"https://bankinnovation.net/subscribe/\" target=\"_blank\"> ...Read More </a></p> </div> </div> </article></div>&#13; </div></div>", 
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><div><div><div>\r\n\r\n            \r\n\r\n            <p>\r\n                Fifth Third Bank Momentum Checking customers can now get access to their paychecks up to two days early.\r\n            </p>\r\n\r\n            <p id=\"ctl00_ctl00_body_mainContent_NewsActicle_pnlBody\">\r\n\tThe US lender began rolling out the Early Pay feature in some markets earlier this year to help customers avoid overdraft fees and the need to turn to payday lenders.<br><br>Fifth Third boasts that its Momentum platform gives customers the local presence of an established lender combined with the innovation of a digital-first bank.<br><br>In addition to Early Pay, customers can get additional time to make deposits to avoid overdraft fees and advances against some future direct deposits.<br><br>Tim Spence, president, Fifth Third, says: &#8220;With Early Pay and Momentum Checking&#8217;s other features, we&#8217;re giving customers the widest range of options to access their money faster and avoid fees.&#8221;\r\n</p>\r\n            \r\n            \r\n\r\n        </div>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n                            \r\n                            </div></div></body></html>")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Here is my code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  cat("\n", "<h1>", i, "</h1>", comment="")
  cat("<hr>")
  cat("  \n#",  data$title[i], "\n", "**Release Date:**")
  cat(data$published[i], "\n")
  cat("  \n",  data$fullcontent[i], "\n","\n","\n") 
}
```

Rendering to html format:
output:
html_document:
toc: yes
highlight: haddock
theme: journal

Comment: You can save your html-page as a PDF-file.